# Is “ruddy” an actual Briticism?

Tags: adjectives, british-english, slang

Is the use of *ruddy* as a pejorative intensifier truly a Briticism? Many dictionaries list it as such, and I've seen it in fiction as a marker that a character is British, but I don't seem to hear actual Brits say it. [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ruddy%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C+ruddy%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cruddy%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cruddy%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0) say it's used just as much on either side of the pond, but especially for a word that's mainly used (in this sense) orally, that's very unreliable.

Is it still in use in the 21st century, and if so is it truly particularly British? If so, is it generally British or is it specific to a particular region or social class? Or is it just one of these words that pass off as British outside the UK because it just doesn't get used much anymore?

Comment: Rowling uses it.

Comment: It is British in the way that *bloody* is a Briticism when used as a swear word, where *ruddy* is a "polite" way of saying *bloody*.  Ngrams will be recording its use in both the pejorative sense and as the adjective meaning a reddish complexion.

Comment: It's a minced oath, and since people are no longer generally taught to mince their oaths as they used to be, its used has lessened. People say _bloody_ or _fucking_ instead. It is definitely mostly BrE, though. Never heard an American use it.

Comment: It's upper middle class or aristocratic British and archaic, you never hear it used any more, a bit like 'dastardly' or 'bounder' or 'cad'.

Comment: @ChrisM I don't really think that's altogether true anymore. Hagrid has given it new life—I do hear it used, mostly by younger people, when they're deliberately mincing their oaths. Twenty years ago, I don't doubt it was old-fashioned, but I'd say it's making a bit of a comeback (or has made one; it may be waning again).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have never heard it used either by youths or older people other than in historical t.v. dramas. It's use by Hagrid may be seen as quaint and, therefore, amusing to copy but it doesn't seem to have caught on amongst the general population.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely  a British expression, an old fashion one:

[Ruddy](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ruddy):

> ***As a British slang euphemism for bloody*** (q.v.), first recorded 1914. (Etymonline)

[Ruddy](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ruddy) (adjective):

> - Ruddy is used by some people to emphasize what they are saying, especially when they are angry.
>     ***[British , old-fashioned , rude , emphasis]***
>
>   - He took the paraffin stove on a picnic and the ruddy thing wouldn't work.

(Collins Dictionary)

[Ruddy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ruddy) (adverb):

> - British Slang 
>     (adverb)
>     *He'd ruddy well better be there.*

(Dictionary.com)

From: [Pelham Grenville  Wodehouse](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/ruddy) “chapter XVIII and XX”, in Jeeves in the Offing, London: Herbert Jenkins, 1960:

> - “Of all the damn silly fatheaded things!” she vociferated, if that's the word. “With a million ruddy names to choose from, these ***ruddy Creams call one ruddy son Wilbert and the other ruddy son Wilfred,*** and both these ***ruddy sons*** are known as Willie. Just going out of their way to mislead the innocent bystander. You'd think people would have more consideration.”

(Wiktionary)

Comment: Yes. As a Brit of a certain age I would only add that my father's generation used it, I might use it occasionally (although half ironically) but I can't imagine my son or his generation using it.

Answer (score 1):

My British-born mother (now 77) uses it quite often, much to my amusement. She would've gotten it from her mother, an Italian Catholic immigrant to Southern England in the late 1920s. She would've minced her oaths as she learned English, I imagine. What makes it more amusing is the extra emphasis put on the minced word, as if to compensate for mincing it!